# Concatenating strings together in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to do something similar to this:

```
char* a = (char*)msg[0];
char* b = (char*)msg[1];
char* c = a + "," + b;
```

Where `msg` is an array of `int`.

N.B.: This is Arduino C++, not regular C++.

Comment: You should use `std::string::operator+`.

Comment: I can't use it in arduino.. I don't know why compiler doesn't know it

Comment: @JongzPuangput are you sure your compiler understands C++, not C?

Comment: Please add the definition of `msg` in your code. Is it an array of strings?

Comment: @JongzPuangput: Then you're not using C++ but C, which is a completely different language.

Comment: @JongzPuangput and don't you think you should have mentioned that you are using a freestanding (in contrast with a hosted) implementation of C++? Have you tried researching at all? The almost-equivalent [`String` class](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/string) is ***trivial*** to find in the documentation.

Comment: @bereal, Arduino's C++ installation is not a hosted environment, it lacks quite a bit of the standard library.

Comment: @datenwolf no, probably not. Arduino's C++ setup does not have `std::string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ string and Arduino String. How to combine them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839990/c-string-and-arduino-string-how-to-combine-them)

Comment: Why are you trying to convert two `int`s to two `char*`s and then add them together. Something is suspiciously wrong here. Perhaps you should add all the relevant information and tell us what it is exactly that you're trying to do...

Comment: I want to add comma in between and set in the function that require char*

Comment: Not good enough. Are you trying to take two `int` values and put them inside a string, where they are separated by a comma?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the body of the question with the answer. Instead, either make a new answer and accept it or accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino doesn't use `std::string`, instead it uses `String` (note the capital S and dropped `std::`). They're used the same way as `std::string` for the most part. So basically you should just be able to do this:

```
String a("hello");
String b(" world");
c = a + b;
```

If you want to convert an integer to a `String`, it has a constructor to do just that, e.g.:

```
String a = String(msg[0]);
String b = String(msg[1]);
```

You can find more examples [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator) and [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor).

Answer (score 1):

See strcat.
You seem to be programming C, not C++.
This should be covered in the most basic tutorials.

Comment: am I misunderstand?? don't arduino is develop in c++??

Comment: @JongzPuangput Usually, when you write code that looks like C, people say "this is not C++". But technically, a lot of C code is also valid C++. Not sure yours is, because I don't know what `msg` is, but the cast to `char*` is likely to be wrong.

Comment: @JongzPuangput That doesn't mean it is not wrong to cast. But there is not enough information to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

so here is my solution thank everyone.

```
  String a = String(msg[0]);
  String b = String(msg[1]);
  String c = a + "," + b;
  char* d;
  c.toCharArray(d,c.length());

  mclient.publish("topic1/sensorAck",d);
```